# StringBuilder or XMLDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, stringbuilder

I have written a console application to fetch some information from a web server, convert it into XML and save it. I have manually created XML (append string using `StringBuilder`). As the XML might be very large is it better to use `StringBuilder` or `XMLDocument` class etc as far as memory is concerned? 
To be precise my question is that if XML is like 10mb text is it memory efficient to use `StringBuilder.append("")` or `System.XML` namespace?

I think a more efficient way would be to use StringBuilder but saving the XML to a file on HD after every iteration and clearing the stringbuilder object. Any comments?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither; I'd use an `XmlWriter`:

```
using(var file = File.Create(path))
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(file))
{
  // write to writer here
}
```

This avoids having to buffer a lot of data in memory, which both `StringBuilder` and `XmlDocument` would do, and avoids all the encoding problems you will face if creating the xml manually (not a good idea, to be honest).

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't manually create XML using a `StringBuilder`, there is just too much room for errors (if it is proper escaping of strings).

To write an XML file of larger size you should use the [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) class.

Comment: You are right I'm aware of it being error prone but my XML is not too complex, it is just too large. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the XSD for the XML I'd use xsd.exe [XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which can generate c# classes from it. 
 From the code it's quite easy to serialize and deserialize the XML so this way you don't have to work with long strings. Just build up your class and save it as a valid XML text.

Comment: Yes I know that but currently I'm only looking for performance. Thanks :)